# Cant align images vertically on carousel

Tags: html, css

**Hello**
I have this web site www.acigaiabeta.esy.es, that im trying to align the images of the carousel to the center vertically, but it´s always stuck to the top.
I even tryed to folow this tip [How to vertically align an image inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div), but still didnt change place.
On big images theres is no big deal, but with small images there is a problem, and the images sizes are random.
what am i missing?

```
.carousel .item {

   vertical-align: middle;
   height: 500px;
   background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  top:auto;
 -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
 -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
 -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
 transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;

}
```

Im only trying by css i tryed using the top, the vertical-align: middle like on the like showed above nothing works.

Comment: Share the code that you tried and didn't work for you!

Comment: update your code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the CSS you need:

```css
#myCarousel img {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, exacly what i need ty so mutch for the help. it worked exacly how i wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```css
.first-slide {
  position: abolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: just did still nothing :( what made it move was if it was position fixed, but it will act for all page and not only inside div :(

Comment: Have you tested your answer before posting it? Welcome to SO. Please take some time to read on [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).